# How to normalize my nested json properly?

Tags: python, json, pandas, nested, normalization

I have json file (named `list_of_beers`) which is a list of 2 beers:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Buzz",
        "tagline": "A Real Bitter Experience.",
        "first_brewed": "09/2007",
        "description": "A light, crisp and bitter IPA brewed with English and American hops. A small batch brewed only once.",
        "image_url": "https://images.punkapi.com/v2/keg.png",
        "abv": 4.5,
        "ibu": 60,
        "target_fg": 1010,
        "target_og": 1044,
        "ebc": 20,
        "srm": 10,
        "ph": 4.4,
        "attenuation_level": 75,
        "volume": {
            "value": 20,
            "unit": "litres"
        },
        "boil_volume": {
            "value": 25,
            "unit": "litres"
        },
        "method": {
            "mash_temp": [
                {
                    "temp": {
                        "value": 64,
                        "unit": "celsius"
                    },
                    "duration": 75
                }
            ],
            "fermentation": {
                "temp": {
                    "value": 19,
                    "unit": "celsius"
                }
            },
            "twist": null
        },
        "ingredients": {
            "malt": [
                {
                    "name": "Maris Otter Extra Pale",
                    "amount": {
                        "value": 3.3,
                        "unit": "kilograms"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "Caramalt",
                    "amount": {
                        "value": 0.2,
                        "unit": "kilograms"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "Munich",
                    "amount": {
                        "value": 0.4,
                        "unit": "kilograms"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "hops": [
                {
                    "name": "Fuggles",
                    "amount": {
                        "value": 25,
                        "unit": "grams"
                    },
                    "add": "start",
                    "attribute": "bitter"
                },
                {
                    "name": "First Gold",
                    "amount": {
                        "value": 25,
                        "unit": "grams"
                    },
                    "add": "start",
                    "attribute": "bitter"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Fuggles",
                    "amount": {
                        "value": 37.5,
                        "unit": "grams"
                    },
                    "add": "middle",
                    "attribute": "flavour"
                },
                {
                    "name": "First Gold",
                    "amount": {
                        "value": 37.5,
                        "unit": "grams"
                    },
                    "add": "middle",
                    "attribute": "flavour"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Cascade",
                    "amount": {
                        "value": 37.5,
                        "unit": "grams"
                    },
                    "add": "end",
                    "attribute": "flavour"
                }
            ],
            "yeast": "Wyeast 1056 - American Ale\u2122"
        },
        "food_pairing": [
            "Spicy chicken tikka masala",
            "Grilled chicken quesadilla",
            "Caramel toffee cake"
        ],
        "brewers_tips": "The earthy and floral aromas from the hops can be overpowering. Drop a little Cascade in at the end of the boil to lift the profile with a bit of citrus.",
        "contributed_by": "Sam Mason <samjbmason>"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Trashy Blonde",
        "tagline": "You Know You Shouldn't",
        "first_brewed": "04/2008",
        "description": "A titillating, neurotic, peroxide punk of a Pale Ale. Combining attitude, style, substance, and a little bit of low self esteem for good measure; what would your mother say? The seductive lure of the sassy passion fruit hop proves too much to resist. All that is even before we get onto the fact that there are no additives, preservatives, pasteurization or strings attached. All wrapped up with the customary BrewDog bite and imaginative twist.",
        "image_url": "https://images.punkapi.com/v2/2.png",
        "abv": 4.1,
        "ibu": 41.5,
        "target_fg": 1010,
        "target_og": 1041.7,
        "ebc": 15,
        "srm": 15,
        "ph": 4.4,
        "attenuation_level": 76,
        "volume": {
            "value": 20,
            "unit": "litres"
        },
        "boil_volume": {
            "value": 25,
            "unit": "litres"
        },
        "method": {
            "mash_temp": [
                {
                    "temp": {
                        "value": 69,
                        "unit": "celsius"
                    },
                    "duration": null
                }
            ],
            "fermentation": {
                "temp": {
                    "value": 18,
                    "unit": "celsius"
                }
            },
            "twist": null
        },
        "ingredients": {
            "malt": [
                {
                    "name": "Maris Otter Extra Pale",
                    "amount": {
                        "value": 3.25,
                        "unit": "kilograms"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "Caramalt",
                    "amount": {
                        "value": 0.2,
                        "unit": "kilograms"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "Munich",
                    "amount": {
                        "value": 0.4,
                        "unit": "kilograms"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "hops": [
                {
                    "name": "Amarillo",
                    "amount": {
                        "value": 13.8,
                        "unit": "grams"
                    },
                    "add": "start",
                    "attribute": "bitter"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Simcoe",
                    "amount": {
                        "value": 13.8,
                        "unit": "grams"
                    },
                    "add": "start",
                    "attribute": "bitter"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Amarillo",
                    "amount": {
                        "value": 26.3,
                        "unit": "grams"
                    },
                    "add": "end",
                    "attribute": "flavour"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Motueka",
                    "amount": {
                        "value": 18.8,
                        "unit": "grams"
                    },
                    "add": "end",
                    "attribute": "flavour"
                }
            ],
            "yeast": "Wyeast 1056 - American Ale\u2122"
        },
        "food_pairing": [
            "Fresh crab with lemon",
            "Garlic butter dipping sauce",
            "Goats cheese salad",
            "Creamy lemon bar doused in powdered sugar"
        ],
        "brewers_tips": "Be careful not to collect too much wort from the mash. Once the sugars are all washed out there are some very unpleasant grainy tasting compounds that can be extracted into the wort.",
        "contributed_by": "Sam Mason <samjbmason>"
    }
]
```

and I'm trying to normalize it using `json_normalize()` from Pandas library:

```
beers_after_normalization = json_normalize(data=list_of_beers)
```

and the output is:

```
| id  |     name       |          tagline           | first_brewed  |                                                                                                                                                                                                                          description                                                                                                                                                                                                                           |               image_url                | abv  | ibu   | target_fg  | target_og  | ebc   | srm   | ph   | attenuation_level  |                                                    food_pairing                                                      |                                                                                      brewers_tips                                                                                       |     contributed_by      | volume.value  | volume.unit  | boil_volume.value  | boil_volume.unit  |                        method.mash_temp                         | method.fermentation.temp.value  | method.fermentation.temp.unit  | method.twist  |                                                                                                       ingredients.malt                                                                                                        |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               ingredients.hops                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 |      ingredients.yeast      |
+=====+================+============================+===============+================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================+========================================+======+=======+============+============+=======+=======+======+====================+======================================================================================================================+=========================================================================================================================================================================================+=========================+===============+==============+====================+===================+=================================================================+=================================+================================+===============+===============================================================================================================================================================================================================================+================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================+=============================+
|  1  | Buzz           | A Real Bitter Experience.  | 09/2007       | A light, crisp and bitter IPA brewed with English and American hops. A small batch brewed only once.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           | https://images.punkapi.com/v2/keg.png  | 4.5  | 60.0  |    1010.0  |    1044.0  | 20.0  | 10.0  | 4.4  |              75.0  | [Spicy chicken tikka masala, Grilled chicken quesadilla, Caramel toffee cake]                                        | The earthy and floral aromas from the hops can be overpowering. Drop a little Cascade in at the end of the boil to lift the profile with a bit of citrus.                               | Sam Mason <samjbmason>  |           20  | litres       |                25  | litres            | [{'temp': {'value': 64, 'unit': 'celsius'}, 'duration': 75}]    |                           19.0  | celsius                        | None          | [{'name': 'Maris Otter Extra Pale', 'amount': {'value': 3.3, 'unit': 'kilograms'}}, {'name': 'Caramalt', 'amount': {'value': 0.2, 'unit': 'kilograms'}}, {'name': 'Munich', 'amount': {'value': 0.4, 'unit': 'kilograms'}}]   | [{'name': 'Fuggles', 'amount': {'value': 25, 'unit': 'grams'}, 'add': 'start', 'attribute': 'bitter'}, {'name': 'First Gold', 'amount': {'value': 25, 'unit': 'grams'}, 'add': 'start', 'attribute': 'bitter'}, {'name': 'Fuggles', 'amount': {'value': 37.5, 'unit': 'grams'}, 'add': 'middle', 'attribute': 'flavour'}, {'name': 'First Gold', 'amount': {'value': 37.5, 'unit': 'grams'}, 'add': 'middle', 'attribute': 'flavour'}, {'name': 'Cascade', 'amount': {'value': 37.5, 'unit': 'grams'}, 'add': 'end', 'attribute': 'flavour'}]  | Wyeast 1056 - American Ale™ |
+-----+----------------+----------------------------+---------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+------+-------+------------+------------+-------+-------+------+--------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+---------------+--------------+--------------------+-------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+
|  2  | Trashy Blonde  | You Know You Shouldn't     | 04/2008       | A titillating, neurotic, peroxide punk of a Pale Ale. Combining attitude, style, substance, and a little bit of low self esteem for good measure; what would your mother say? The seductive lure of the sassy passion fruit hop proves too much to resist. All that is even before we get onto the fact that there are no additives, preservatives, pasteurization or strings attached. All wrapped up with the customary BrewDog bite and imaginative twist.  | https://images.punkapi.com/v2/2.png    | 4.1  | 41.5  |    1010.0  |    1041.7  | 15.0  | 15.0  | 4.4  |              76.0  | [Fresh crab with lemon, Garlic butter dipping sauce, Goats cheese salad, Creamy lemon bar doused in powdered sugar]  | Be careful not to collect too much wort from the mash. Once the sugars are all washed out there are some very unpleasant grainy tasting compounds that can be extracted into the wort.  | Sam Mason <samjbmason>  |           20  | litres       |                25  | litres            | [{'temp': {'value': 69, 'unit': 'celsius'}, 'duration': None}]  |                           18.0  | celsius                        | None          | [{'name': 'Maris Otter Extra Pale', 'amount': {'value': 3.25, 'unit': 'kilograms'}}, {'name': 'Caramalt', 'amount': {'value': 0.2, 'unit': 'kilograms'}}, {'name': 'Munich', 'amount': {'value': 0.4, 'unit': 'kilograms'}}]  | [{'name': 'Amarillo', 'amount': {'value': 13.8, 'unit': 'grams'}, 'add': 'start', 'attribute': 'bitter'}, {'name': 'Simcoe', 'amount': {'value': 13.8, 'unit': 'grams'}, 'add': 'start', 'attribute': 'bitter'}, {'name': 'Amarillo', 'amount': {'value': 26.3, 'unit': 'grams'}, 'add': 'end', 'attribute': 'flavour'}, {'name': 'Motueka', 'amount': {'value': 18.8, 'unit': 'grams'}, 'add': 'end', 'attribute': 'flavour'}]                                                                                                                | Wyeast 1056 - American Ale™ |
+-----+----------------+----------------------------+---------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+------+-------+------------+------------+-------+-------+------+--------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+---------------+--------------+--------------------+-------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+
```

But as you can see there are still few columns to normalize: `method.mash_temp`, `ingredients.malt`, `ingredients.hops`. And my question how to do this? I tried to use:

```py
json_normalize(data=list_of_beers, record_path = ['method.mash_temp', 'ingredients.malt',
'ingredients.hops'], meta=['id', 'name', 'tagline', 'first_brewed', 'description', 'image_url',
       'abv', 'ibu', 'target_fg', 'target_og', 'ebc', 'srm', 'ph',
       'attenuation_level', 'food_pairing', 'brewers_tips', 'contributed_by',
       'volume.value', 'volume.unit', 'boil_volume.value', 'boil_volume.unit',
       'method.fermentation.temp.value',
       'method.fermentation.temp.unit', 'method.twist',
       'ingredients.yeast'])
```

but unfortunately there was some KeyErrors ;/ I also tried to first normalize my 3 nested columns (i.e. `method.mash_temp`, `ingredients.malt` and `ingredients.hops`) and then to join this each column to my table but to be honest I fell on merging my table with these 3 columns -.- It would be nice if someone show me different approaches to this problem. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You would have to create separate dataframes for each record path at the same level and then merge them based on the keys, or leave them as separate dataframes:

```
df_hops = pd.json_normalize(data['listofbeers'],
                       record_path=['ingredients', 'hops'], 
                       meta=[['id'], ['name']],
                       record_prefix='hops.')

df_malt = pd.json_normalize(data['listofbeers'],
                       record_path=['ingredients', 'malt'], 
                       meta=[['id'], ['name']],
                       record_prefix='malt.')

df_method = pd.json_normalize(data['listofbeers'],
                       record_path=['method', 'mash_temp'], 
                       meta=[['id'], ['name']],
                       record_prefix='method.')

df = pd.concat([df_hops, df_malt], join='inner', axis=1)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
   hops.name hops.add hops.attribute  hops.amount.value hops.amount.unit  ...               malt.name malt.amount.value malt.amount.unit  id           name
0     Fuggles    start         bitter               25.0            grams  ...  Maris Otter Extra Pale              3.30        kilograms   1           Buzz
1  First Gold    start         bitter               25.0            grams  ...                Caramalt              0.20        kilograms   1           Buzz
2     Fuggles   middle        flavour               37.5            grams  ...                  Munich              0.40        kilograms   1           Buzz
3  First Gold   middle        flavour               37.5            grams  ...  Maris Otter Extra Pale              3.25        kilograms   2  Trashy Blonde
4     Cascade      end        flavour               37.5            grams  ...                Caramalt              0.20        kilograms   2  Trashy Blonde
5    Amarillo    start         bitter               13.8            grams  ...                  Munich              0.40        kilograms   2  Trashy Blonde
```

Another approach is to use `flatten_json`, documentation here -> [Flatten JSON docs](https://github.com/amirziai/flatten#usage-with-pandas), you can create your own recursive function based on this module.